# session_store initializer working in production, but not development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, initializer

I have a site with multiple subdomains, and have added `:domain => :all` to my session store as follows, so that my logins persist across all subdomains.

```
`MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_MyApp_session', :domain => :all`
```

Although this seems to be working in production, I can't get my sessions to work across domains when in development. What could be causing this, and what can I add/delete from my config or environment files to make my development sessions match my production sessions?

Please let me know if there are specific lines of code that I need to check, and I will do so (or paste them in here).
Thanks much for the feedback!

Comment: Which hosts (addresses) do you use to access the site in development and in production? Check if this post, http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm using lvh.me as well, so easy answer. (Always seems so easy after the fact). If you enter this (e.g. "use 'name_of_development_url" instead of ":all" during development"), I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the solution from @dimuch's [link](http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/), and am setting the domain to `:all` during production and setting it to my development url of `'lvh.me'` during development.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to troubleshoot the problem.

1) Check to see if the backticks are causing the problem.

2) Check to see if any other initializers or Rails-related initialization problems are causing the application not to load when booted on your production server.

Comment: Thanks @matsko. What do you mean by backticks? Also, regarding your second point, the session setting are working in production, but not in development. Do you know of any initialization problems that may cause this? The app itself loads into both environments, but the session_store initialization seems to be loaded only in production.